# The input is not being taken by the Microphone on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: sound, virtualbox, microphone

After lots of googling, I am fed up now. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS(32 bit) on VirtualBox 5.2. VirtualBox is installed in Windows 10(64 bit).From windows, microphone works very well. But in Ubuntu, its a pain. I can hear the sound (although not very well) but cannot take input, means nobody listen to me. Please Help...

System:
HP Probook 450g1
Processor : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200M CPU @2.50GHz 2.50GHz